# What is the best antonym for the noun "analogue", as in "a good analogue"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

I want to express a comparison between two concepts but emphasize their difference rather than their similarities.

Am I wrong in assuming that "analogue" connotes similarity?

Sample sentence: "In terms of walkability, Boston is a good [analogue] to sprawling Western cities like Phoenix or Salt Lake City."

Comment: I have formulated a tentative answer, but it would help a lot if you were to offer a sample sentence or two involving the word you seek, as is standard practice hereabouts.

Comment: "Digital", obviously.  ;)  (Actually, "contrasting" is one possibility, depending on how you want to use the word.  "Orthogonal" is another term that might fit certain cases.)

Comment: lol @HotLicks :)

Comment: Thesaurus.com doesn't come up with any useful antonyms for "analogue", but it does come up with these for "correspondence":      *clash difference disagreement discord disproportion dissimilarity imbalance incongruity irregularity mismatch  opposition  refusal unlikeness*.

Comment: I'm not sure if *oxymoron* could be used metahorically or if this sentence would make any sense at all, but what about *In terms of walkability, Boston and sprawling Western cities are like an oxymoron*.

Comment: How about "antithesis"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Hot Licks, *contrast* may be the word you are looking for. At least it's a good bet.

Dictionary.com:

> [*contrast*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contrast?s=t): a striking exhibition of unlikeness

Your example:

> "In terms of walkability, Boston is a good *contrast* to sprawling
>   Western cities like Phoenix or Salt Lake City."

Another good possibility, even more of an antonym, is *antipode*.

Dictionary.com:

> [*antipode*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antipode?s=t): a direct
>   or exact opposite

Your example:

> "In terms of walkability, Boston is an *antipode* to sprawling
>   Western cities like Phoenix or Salt Lake City."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it is a ***counterexample*** - an example which is opposite to the one(s) it is being compared to, in the specific context.

> "In terms of walkability, Boston is a good ***counterexample*** to
>   sprawling Western cities like Phoenix or Salt Lake City."

ODO:

> **[counterexample](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/counterexample)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> An example that opposes or contradicts an idea or theory:
>   ‘the media
>   presented him as a counterexample to the common stereotypes’
>
> ‘As a counterexample, another firm in a similar situation abandoned
>   their original facility consolidation plan.’

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not wrong. For the antonym, try ***[antitype](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antitype)***:

> An opposite or contrasting type (American Heritage)
>   An opposite type (Collins)

Both dictionaries number this sense 2, following one involving linkages between Old and New Testaments; but the word is perfectly serviceable for this second sense.